# PHP: Function Not Working

Tags: php, function

```
<?php


$V = "Stormy";
$W = "Heavy thunderstorms";

function getMyString($SentenceSrc)
{
    if ((strpos($SentenceSrc,'Heavy thunderstorms')!== true) OR (strpos($SentenceSrc,'Heavy t-storms')!== true))
     $SentenceVariable = "Rains with gusty winds";

    elseif ((strpos($SentenceSrc,'Sun')!== true) OR (strpos($SentenceSrc,'sun')!== true))
        $SentenceVariable = "Sunny";
    elseif ((strpos($SentenceSrc,'Stormy')!== true))
        $SentenceVariable = "Stormy";
    else
        $SentenceVariable = "Partly cloudy ";

    return $SentenceVariable;
}



echo getMyString($V);
echo getMyString($W);


?>
```

This is my code. The output should be:

```
StormyRains with gusty winds
```

But instead, it only reads the first part of the condition, and returns it True, when it is false.

my `getMyString($SentenceSrc)` is supposed to find a string within a given string and return a weather condition whenever the given string returns true.

Comment: strpos returns a number (the position) or false (never true), I don't know if comparing `strpos()!==true` is doing something, try comparing to false

Comment: Instead of `OR`, you should try to use `||`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your `!== true` to `> -1`

```
<?php
$V = "Stormy";
$W = "Heavy thunderstorms";

function getMyString($SentenceSrc)
{
    if ((strpos($SentenceSrc,'Heavy thunderstorms') > -1) OR (strpos($SentenceSrc,'Heavy t-storms') > -1))
        $SentenceVariable = "Rains with gusty winds";
    elseif ((strpos($SentenceSrc,'Sun') > -1) OR (strpos($SentenceSrc,'sun') > -1))
        $SentenceVariable = "Sunny";
    elseif ((strpos($SentenceSrc,'Stormy') > -1))
        $SentenceVariable = "Stormy";
    else
        $SentenceVariable = "Partly cloudy ";

    return $SentenceVariable;
}

echo getMyString($V);
echo '<br />';
echo getMyString($W);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask for an explanation to this?

Comment: +1 for quick answer. i also posted the answer but because you have given first i have deleted my post

Comment: @Clary If found something, return the location of the matching phrase/substring and if none, return false. But for some reason, === false is not working on mine so we just look for int greater than -1 because the start of the string is 0. so yeah.

Comment: That's because you're checking different things there. If you're checking for `> -1` you're checking for a `true`. If you do a check on `===false` you're checking on a `false`. Execute following code: `<?php
if (strpos("test", "test") > -1)
 echo "success";

if (strpos("test", "test") === false)
 echo "success";
?>` The first one will return success because 'test' is in the string 'test'. The second one will fail because 'test' is in 'test' and therefor will not return false.

Answer (score 0):

`strpos($a, $b)!==true` is always false, because `strpos` returns an integer when the string is found.

Use `strpos($a, $b) === false` instead.

Comment: For the boolean logic to keep working, you'll have to change the `OR` to `AND` also.

Answer (score 0):

It is functioning the way you have written it. `strpos` **never** returns ***true***. It eigther returns position of the needle if found or false.

So your first condition always correct.

What you need to do is:

```
if ((strpos($SentenceSrc,'Heavy thunderstorms')=== false) OR (strpos($SentenceSrc,'Heavy t-storms')=== false))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    function getMyString($SentenceSrc)
    {
        if (stristr($SentenceSrc,'Heavy thunderstorms') || stristr($SentenceSrc,'Heavy t-storms')){
            $SentenceVariable = "Rains with gusty winds";
        }
        elseif (stristr($SentenceSrc,'Sun') || stristr($SentenceSrc,'sun')){
            $SentenceVariable = "Sunny";
        }
        elseif (stristr($SentenceSrc,'Stormy')){
            $SentenceVariable = "Stormy";
        }
        else {
            $SentenceVariable = "Partly cloudy ";
        }
        return $SentenceVariable;
    }
```